# $u_{tt} + au_t = c^2u_{xx}$ for some $a>0$ implies that the energy is not increasing

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Could someone please help me with the following question? I got stuck somewhere.

---

Given a function $u(t,x)$ satisfying the relationship:
$$
u_{tt} + au_t \ = \ c^2u_{xx} \qquad \text{ for some } a>0
$$
And the requirement that holds for sufficiently big $x$:
$$
\exists\alpha>0, \ \exists C(x)>0, \ 
\max \{|u_t(t,x)|,|u_x(t,x)|\} \leq\frac{ C(t)}{|x|^\alpha} 
$$
Show that the energy function $E(T)$ as defined below is a nonincreasing solution.
$$
E(t) \ = \ \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2 + c^2u_x^2 dx
$$

---

**What I tried **

I just took its derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E(t) 
\ = \ 
\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[u_t^2 + c^2u_x^2\right] dx
\ = \
\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_tu_{tt} + c^2u_xu_{tx}dx
$$
And $u_{tt} \ = \ -au_t +c^2u_{xx}$, so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E(t) 
\ = \ 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t(-au_t +c^2u_{xx}) + c^2u_xu_{tx}dx
\ = \ 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t(-au_t +c^2u_{xx}) + c^2u_xu_{tx}dx
\ = \ 
c^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_xu_{xt}+u_tu_{xx}dx - a \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2dx 
$$
How could I show that this is greater than zero? In tried to find primitives but I failed.

Comment: You made a typo in your second to last line, it should read..

\begin{align}
c^{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t} u_{xx} + u_{x} u_{tx} dx - a \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t}^{2} dx = c^{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \partial_{x} (u_{t} u_{x}) dx - a \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t}^{2} dx
\end{align}

Then use the fact that 

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{t}^{2} dx$$

is always positive.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(t) 
\ = \  
c^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_{x}u_{xt}+u_tu_{xx}dx - a \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2dx 
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(t) 
\ = \  
c^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial (u_t u_x)}{\partial x}dx - a \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2dx 
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(t) 
\ = \  
c^2 \left( (u_t u_x)_{x=+\infty} - (u_t u_x)_{x=-\infty}  \right)  - a \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2dx 
$$
Here, we see that possibly something is missing in the wording of the problem : It should be stated that $u(x,t)$ is a function which has FINITE limits at infinity , especially if this function is the model of a physical phenomena or process. If we suppose that this assumption is true, then the derivative at infinity is zero. So, $\left( (u_t u_x)_{x=+\infty} - (u_t u_x)_{x=-\infty}  \right)=0$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(t) =  - a \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_t^2dx 
$$
The integral is $\geq 0$ and $a>0$ . Hense $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E(t)\leq 0$  and $E(t)$ is not increassing.

Comment: Yes, you where right. Let me add that requirement.

Comment: How does $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} u(x,t) = 0$ imply $\lim_{|x|}u_t(x,t) =0$? I know $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} u_x(x,t) = 0$.

Comment: In general $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u (x,t) = C$ does not imply that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u_x (x,t) = 0$ holds true. This is explained [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996529/construction-of-function-with-function-going-to-0-but-derivative-not-as-x-tends) In particular, $u_x(x, t)$ might approach $\pm \infty$ (or oscillate between $\infty$ and $-\infty$) for $x \to \pm \infty$. A good example is $u(x, t) = \sin\big(x^3\big) / x $. So how do you know that $u_tu_x \Big \vert_{x \to - \infty}^{x \to + \infty} = 0$ holds without any additional control on $u_t, u_x$?