# About a real, differentiable function with an oblique asymptote.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a real, differentiable function f with an oblique asymptote, i.e. $lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)-ax-b=0$. Does this imply that $lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=a?$

It makes intuitive sense, but coming up with a proof in terms of epsilon-delta definitions eludes me.

Is there a theorem on this, or a proof one of you could come up with?

Comment: This counterexample answers your question: [Construction of function with function going to 0 but derivative not as X tends to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996529/construction-of-function-with-function-going-to-0-but-derivative-not-as-x-tends) E.g. $f(x)=ax+b+\frac{\sin(x^2)}x.$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any suggestions on how to find counter examples to things I conjecture like this?

Comment: Googling with keywords, or [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_1%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7De%5E%7Bkx%7Dx%5E%7B%5Calpha%7Ddx%24&p=1) with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} =0$. Hospital rule does't ask your question?